# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject error mvc asp.net newtonjson

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use `HttpRequestMessage` my model is some different **VirtualStock**. My API JSON model as below

```
[{
        "_id": "5f2d66ae6abb1d6870e926ac",
        "MessageId": "EAD8B97887FFC1F180F3005056BF2302",
        "MessageType": "CreateDiscount",
        "RequestedBy": "AAA",
        "RequestedDate": "2020-08-07T17:22:58.000Z",
        "Data": {
            "_id": "5f2d66ae6abb1d6870e926ad",
            "Sku": "A",
            "SkuId": "EAD8B97887FFC0F180F3005056BF2302",
            "Price": 1759.17,
            "PurchasePrice": 1768.88,
            "StartDateTime": "2020-08-07T17:24:34.000Z",
            "EndDateTime": "2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "VirtualStock": "1000",
            "MaximumQuantityForCart": 10,
            "CurrencyCode": "949"
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f2d65daf7168b686d9474b9",
        "MessageId": "EAD8B8F92D90CDF180F3005056BF2302",
        "MessageType": "UpdateDiscount",
        "RequestedBy": "AAA",
        "RequestedDate": "2020-08-07T17:19:26.000Z",
        "Data": {
            "_id": "5f2d65daf7168b686d9474c5",
            "Sku": "A",
            "SkuId": "EAD8B8F92D90C5F180F3005056BF2302",
            "DiscountId": "8c3975a0-ea85-48e9-9c31-ea488bdad5c4",
            "Price": 296.2,
            "PurchasePrice": 239.91,
            "StartDateTime": "2020-08-01T14:35:00.000Z",
            "EndDateTime": "2020-08-07T17:23:08.000Z",
            "VirtualStock": {
                "Value": "100",
                "IsAssigned": true
            },
            "MaximumQuantityForCart": 25,
            "CurrencyCode": "949"
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I defined my model VirtualStock like object and nullable.

```
public object? VirtualStock { get; set; }
```

but I get error parsing how can fix this?

I saw with debug Deserialize Success but showing JSON GetDiscount method I have exceptions

**controller code as below**

```
public IActionResult Discount()
{
    return View();
}
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDiscount()
{
    return Json(new { data = await _log.GetAllAsync("http://0.0.0.0/DiscountLog?pagesize=9&page=16") });
}
```

**my Repository**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(string url)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
        };

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(jsonString,jsonSerializerSettings);
    }

    return null;
}
```

**My error:**

[image: my error]

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> NotSupportedException: The collection type 'System.Object' on
> 'RetailLogWeb.Models.LogItem.VirtualStock' is not supported.
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable<TClass,
> TDeclaredProperty, TRuntimeProperty,
> TConverter>.GetDictionaryKeyAndValueFromGenericDictionary(ref
> WriteStackFrame writeStackFrame, out string key, out object value)
>
> NotSupportedException: The collection type 'System.Object' on
> 'RetailLogWeb.Models.LogItem.VirtualStock' is not supported.
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable<TClass,
> TDeclaredProperty, TRuntimeProperty,
> TConverter>.GetDictionaryKeyAndValueFromGenericDictionary(ref
> WriteStackFrame writeStackFrame, out string key, out object value)
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.GetDictionaryKeyAndValue(ref
> WriteStackFrame writeStackFrame, out string key, out object value)
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleDictionary(JsonClassInfo
> elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, ref WriteStack state)
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int
> originalWriterDepth, int flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions
> options, ref WriteStack state)
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, object
> value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, JsonResult result)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, JsonResult result)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
> Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
> bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
> next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Comment: Try researching the error. You can't serialize into `object`.

Comment: i searced but not find result

Comment: Could you post some code and show which line is failing?

Comment: i post edit i have get error my get method json result GetDiscount @TawabWakil

Comment: This is ASP.NET Core, correct?  You may want to add that to the question tags to get the right folks looking at the question.  Also, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204435/migration-to-net-core-3-1-netwonsoft-missing) post help at all?

Comment: I added services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(); it's works! thnks man :) @TawabWakil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP figured it out as shared in the comments, but I'll provide an answer here just to close out the question.  As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204435/migration-to-net-core-3-1-netwonsoft-missing) answer, the solution was to add a variant of this line:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

This was needed because `Newtonsoft.Json` was removed during a recent upgrade to .NET Core, and this adds it back in.  Note that this assumes you have the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package installed.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).